# Converting Comma Separated Value to Double Quotes comma separated string

Tags: php, string, double

I have a comma separated value like

```
alpha,beta,charlie
```

how can I convert it to

```
"alpha","beta","charlie"
```

using a single function in php without using `str_replace`?

Comment: I don't want to have multiple line of code to perform this. I thought there might be an inbuilt function in php to do this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Alternatively to Richard Parnaby-King's function (shorter):

```
function addQuotes($string) {
    return '"'. implode('","', explode(',', $string)) .'"';
}

echo addQuotes('alpha,beta,charlie'); // = "alpha","beta","charlie"
```

Comment: Not only shorter, but without useless loops and string concatenation

Comment: Hey jexat, Thanks for your reply but i was looking for a inbuilt function. But i think using str_replace is better option then if i want less line of code. code is here : $rolestring = "'".str_replace(",","','",$roles)."'";

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Take a comma separated string and place double quotes around each value.
 * @param String $string comma separated string, eg 'alpha,beta,charlie'
 * @return String comma separated, quoted values, eg '"alpha","beta","charlie"'
 */
function addQuote($string)
{
  $array = explode(',', $string);
  $newArray = array();
  foreach($array as $value)
  {
    $newArray[] = '"' . $value . '"';
  }
  $newString = implode(',', $newArray);
  return $newString;
}
```

`echo addQuote('alpha,beta,charlie'); // results in: "alpha","beta","charlie"`

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
    <?php
    $arr = spliti(",","alpha,beta,charlie");
    for($i=0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++)
    $var = $var . '"' . $arr[$i] . '",';

    //to avoid comma at the end
    $var = substr($var, 0,-1);
    echo $var;
?>
```

with function:

```
<?php
function AddQuotes($str){
    $arr = spliti(",",$str);
    for($i=0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++)
    $var = $var . '"' . $arr[$i] . '",';

    //to avoid comma at the end
    $var = substr($var, 0,-1);
    echo $var;
}
AddQuotes("alpha,beta,charlie");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i was looking for a inbuilt function or very less line of code. So i think using str_replce is better like $rolestring = "'".str_replace(",","','",$roles)."'";